# React exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, react-dom

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRLS3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sv3k.png)

I downloaded react and react dom from console. I downloaded babel. I set up a very simple react structure. I run babeli and run index html from live server. but it gives an error like this.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
> at app.js:5:23

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class AppRouter extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <>
            adsada
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default AppRouter;
```

---

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import AppRouter from './routers/AppRouter'


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<AppRouter/>);
```

I read somewhere that the browser cannot convert expressions like "require" or "export". so it says i have to use tools like webpack. This is the cause of the error. So how can I fix this without using them? nobody knows. interesting :D